# How to properly work with third-party libraries in Pyro v.4.63

Tags: python, pyro, pyro4

I'm a bit confused with working with remote third-party libraries:

**1) For example,**
I have server code:

```
import Pyro4
import Pyro4.naming
import Pyro4.utils.flame
Pyro4.config.REQUIRE_EXPOSE = False
Pyro4.config.FLAME_ENABLED = True
Pyro4.config.SERIALIZERS_ACCEPTED = set(["pickle"])
Pyro4.config.SERIALIZER = 'pickle'  # for flameserver


def _main():
    """Start RPC server."""
    ip_address = Pyro4.socketutil.getIpAddress(None, workaround127=True)
    ns_daemon = Pyro4.naming.NameServerDaemon(host=ip_address, port=RPC_PORT)
    Pyro4.utils.flame.start(ns_daemon)

    from remote_management.rpc.component.shell import Shell
    shell_uri = ns_daemon.register(Shell())
    ns_daemon.nameserver.register("shell", shell_uri)
    from remote_management.rpc.component.cpu import CPU
    cpu_uri = ns_daemon.register(CPU())
    ns_daemon.nameserver.register("cpu", cpu_uri)

    ns_daemon.requestLoop()
    ns_daemon.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

The CPU component is like this:

```
import psutil

class CPU(object):
    def ps(self):
        return psutil.cpu_times()
```

When I use it in client like this:

```
import Pyro4
import Pyro4.utils.flame
import Pyro4.errors

Pyro4.config.SERIALIZER = "pickle"

proxy = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:cpu@myhost:47976")
print proxy.ps()
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 145, in <module>
    print proxy.ps()
  File "/home/korolev/.envs/auto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/core.py", line 187, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/korolev/.envs/auto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/core.py", line 464, in _pyroInvoke
    data = serializer.deserializeData(msg.data, compressed=msg.flags & message.FLAGS_COMPRESSED)
  File "/home/korolev/.envs/auto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/util.py", line 170, in deserializeData
    return self.loads(data)
  File "/home/korolev/.envs/auto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/util.py", line 451, in loads
        return pickle.loads(data)

ImportError: No module named psutil._pslinux
```

As you see it cannot be deserialized. And if I change return to:

`return tuple(psutil.cpu_times())`, then it works.

**2) I think this next problem has the same nature:**
The server code is almost the same except component

```
from remote_management.rpc.component.registrator import ModuleRegistrator
reg_uri = ns_daemon.register(ModuleRegistrator())
ns_daemon.nameserver.register("module_registrator", reg_uri)
```

If I need remote module, but don't have it locally, why I can't do just like this:

Registrator component:

```
class ModuleRegistrator(object):
    def register(self, module):
        module = importlib.import_module(module)
        self._pyroDaemon.register(module)
        return module
```

so when I use it in client:

```
proxy = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:module_registrator@myhost:47976")
print proxy.register("psutil").cpu_times()
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 145, in <module>
    print proxy.register('psutil').cpu_times()
  File "/home/korolev/.envs/auto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/core.py", line 279, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("remote object '%s' has no exposed attribute or method '%s'" % (self._pyroUri, name))
AttributeError: remote object 'PYRONAME:module_registrator@myhost:47976' has no exposed attribute or method 'register'
```

Please help me understand this errors and where I'm missing something? And what is the best approach to handle things like this when working with third-party remotely? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll try to answer this later, but first let me ask: how familiar are you with ``pickle`` and the restrictions it has?

Comment: Thanks. I know `pickle` very superficial, I caught the general concept only - that it is used for (de)serializing python objects. With the restrictions my knowledge almost the same - somewhere I've read, that PyTime objects can't be pickled and the scope of defined class is matters too(can be imported). But I'll dig for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you seem to be using the 'flame' feature of Pyro4, which requires the `pickle` serialization protocol. This is powerful, but not without problems.
Are you sure you want/need to use flame? I hope you are aware of its security implications. http://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flame.html

Now, your actual question consists of three parts (try to make your future questions more about just a single issue, that makes answering them a lot simpler)

#### To answer the first part of your question:

As you already found out yourself, you cannot assume that all types can just be transported over the network and magically just work on the other side. Especially with `pickle` this only works if the module in which 
the type is defined, is available on both sides. 
In your case, it seems that the `psutil` module is not available on your client side, hence the pickle error when it tries to deserialize the object returned by `psutil.cpu_times()`.

The solution could be to install `psutil` on your client side as well.
You also discovered an alternative solution: don't pass objects of custom types over the wire, but stick to builtin types as much as possible. When you convert the result to a tuple or list or dict,
these can be serialized and deserialized without any issues (if all the objects they contain are of a builtin type as well).

#### To answer the second part of your question:

This code looks like you're trying to find a workaround for the problem in the first question?
Anyway, the error should be clear; it means what it says: that the remote object your proxy is connected to, doesn't have the method exposed that you're trying to call. You should add a `@Pyro4.expose` decoration
to properly expose it.

That said, you're already using Flame, so why aren't you using its remote module feature? See http://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flame.html#flame-object-and-examples

For example (I assume you installed `psutil` on the client side):

```
import Pyro4.utils.flame

Pyro4.config.SERIALIZER = "pickle"
flame = Pyro4.utils.flame.connect("yourhost:9999")

psutilmodule = flame.module("psutil")
print("remote cpu:", psutilmodule.cpu_times())
```

#### Finally,

to address your question "what is the best approach to handle things like this when working with third-party remotely":

- try not to expose the details and types of the API you're working with, reduce it to builtin types as much as possible. 
  http://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tipstricks.html#consider-using-basic-data-types-instead-of-custom-classes
  If you're doing this correctly, you can also simply use Pyro's default serializer (serpent) instead of pickle, and not have any security issues. (that does require a solution that does not depend on flame, see next bullet)
- *don't use Flame unless you're absolutely certain that you are okay with its security implications and that you can't solve your issue another way*. Instead create a normal Pyro server class with a dedicated custom API that you wrote yourself.
- only expose the remote methods that you actually need to have accessible remotely.

Comment: First of all, thank you - now the whole picture is clearer to me.

In relation to using 'flame' feature - yes, I'm aware of its security implications. That's OK for me, cause I'm using it in my auto-tests.

As for second part of the question - I've set `Pyro4.config.REQUIRE_EXPOSE = False` so I expected that it's not necessary to obviously add `Pyro4.expose`.

Anyway, I'll go further with the alternative -prepare methods on remote machine, that will convert to builtin types, because I can't install third-parties on build agents.

Comment: Ok, REQUIRE_EXPOSE=False should indeed auto-expose everything. It's weird that this gives the error you're seeing. I may dig into this a bit further to see what's up with that

Comment: I've tried running the source you provided but I cannot reproduce the error you're reporting. I'm getting other errors which are explained because you're trying to return a module and as I already explained, that doesn't work. If you're still running into problems, ask a new question with the actual source code and exact error you're getting.  One last tip: if you're using the PYRONAME uri scheme, you usually don't have to provide the hostname and port in the uri